# Template file not synchronizing to cms?

Tags: templates, sync

I have been given an expressionengine site to work on. This is my first time using expressionengine.

I am trying to make some changes to a template file. I have uploaded the file to the webserver. I then go in to desgin > templates > synchronize templates.

The template file that I edited shows a different "File edit date" to the date that I just edited the file.

I ran the synchronizaton on this file anyway to see if it would work and it didn't do anything.

How can I synchronize changes to template files back to the live site/cms?

Comment: EECMS always use the most recent version of the template. It doesn't matter if it is on a file or on database.

Are you sure you're editing the right file?

Answer (score 3):

Check a few things in EE. Go to DESIGN > TEMPLATES > GLOBAL PREFERENCES and check out the last two settings.

- Save Templates as Files -> Yes (if it won't change, check your config
  files)
- Server path to site's templates -> make sure path is correct and folder is chmod 777

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes people develop templates as files, then when they launch on the production server they sync those to the DB and then turn off saving to file (for performance reasons I believe) - so then it wouldn't pick up the changed template I guess.

Answer (score 2):

You might check the cache option;

Find the template, go to preferences and see if "enable caching" is set to "no". 
When you're done editing simply switch back to "yes" .

Answer (score 1):

On a webserver make sure the files are set to the correct file permissions, which should be rw-rw-rw- 666

Answer (score 0):

Can I just say EE template sync is lacking. The sync manager doesn't tell you which direction the sync will go in. You should be able to manually toggle direction however you want on a case by case basis. Why can I check some boxes and not others, why are some dates red and some green? There should also be a setting that if file is newer, auto sync to db or if db is newer, auto sync to file. And do that on an ongoing basis if configured. That's what I'd expect. The way they have it leaves a lot to the unknown.